# Facebook - "attachments" modifier - get all possible types

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I create a script which will embed all posts from my group on my website. To do that, I have to know all possible types of modifier "attachments".

Now I know, that type can be:

- share,
- video_share_youtube.

But I don't know where I can find all these types? I need this types to create good design in HTML, for example when attachment type is video_share_youtube, I know this attachment is youtube movie. If type is "share" it's just pasted a url into text message. But I know that not all types of attachments.

Here is my code:

```
$response = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/$group_id/feed?fields=videos,from,picture,message,full_picture&limit=$limit&access_token=$token");
$response = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/$group_id/feed?fields=attachments,description,full_picture,picture,story,source,created_time,from,message&locale=pl_PL&limit=$limit&access_token=$token");
$array = json_decode($response, true);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The question is, what are the types you are interested in for your website, as the file types are vast. Basically, I did this.

Created a file with possible formats  (.doc, .txt, .pdf, .jpeg etc.,), attach it to the message and observe response from graph api.
The most possible types from mime_type field are,

1. application/pdf
2. application/msword
3. text/plain
4. image/jpeg
5. image/gif

"data": [
                {
                  "id": "abcd",
                  "mime_type": "text/plain",
                  "name": "Sample 1.txt",
                  "size": 12,
                  "file_url": ""
                },
                {
                  "id": "abcd",
                  "mime_type": "text/plain",
                  "name": "Sample2.txt",
                  "size": 12,
                  "file_url": ""
                }
    ]